# Preparation of links in the loop

Tags: angularjs, cycle

There is an array of objects. I sort out of its loop.
In both series to get a link to the image?
vm.data.list- array of object.
Loop:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in vm.data.list">
              <td ng-bind="item.temp.day"></td>
              <td ng-bind="vm.symbal"></td>
              <td ng-bind-template="{{ item.humidity }} %"></td>
                       </tr>
```

As in the cycle of getting links to the image? (http://openweathermap.org/img/w/vm.data.list[0].weather[0].icon.png, http://openweathermap.org/img/w/vm.data.list[1].weather[0].icon.png and other)

I tried to do so:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.data.list">
              <td ng-bind="item.temp.day"></td>
              <td ng-bind="vm.symbal"></td>
              <td ng-bind-template="{{ item.humidity }} %"></td>
        <!--      <td img ng-src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{{item.weather[0].icon.png}}">-->
              <td> <img src=http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{{item}}.weather[0].icon.png></td>
              </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `ng-src` instead of `src`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc. Angular will first compute the ng-src value and then construct the src for you.

Here is a basic example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yv5a8zh7/):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <img ng-src="http://www.w3schools.com/{{item.f.folders[0]}}/{{item.name}}">
</div>
```

In your case, use :

```
<img ng-src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w{{item.weather[0].icon}}.png‌​">
```

Aside from the ng-src, be aware that:

- an url beginning with something else than a protocol or a slash is *relative*: it will be resolved against the context of the current page. In your case, don't forget the **http://** at the beginning !
- all the angular expression inside the link should be inside the brackets: `{{item}}.weather[0]` won't work

Comment: Like this?   <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.data.list">
                  <td ng-bind="item.temp.day"></td>
                  <td ng-bind="vm.symbal"></td>
                  <td ng-bind-template="{{ item.humidity }} %"></td>
            <!--      <td img ng-src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{{item.weather[0].icon.png}}">-->
                  <td> <img ng-src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{{item}}.weather[0].icon.png"></td>
                  </tr>

Comment: Like this?   <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.data.list"> <td> <img ng-src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{{item}}.weather[0].icon.png"></td>
                  </tr> Not work.

Comment: see my edited answer. The whole angular expression should be inside the {{ }}.

Comment: If I use Your edit answer,  I don't see any icon.     <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.data.list">
              
                  <td> <img ng-src="openweathermap.org/img/w/{{item.weather[0].icon.png‌​}}"></td>
                  </tr>

Comment: give us an example of your data, it could help. And also have a look at the generated src attribute. How does it look ?

Comment: My data is json responce. Where icon (for example 13d) is are part of the address  http://openweathermap.org/forecast5 (jcon answer) http://openweathermap.org/forecast5

Comment: Name of icon in here: vm.data.list[0].weather[0].icon

Comment: in this case, simply correct my code and don't include .png inside the brackets ! see edited answer.

Comment: But it dobt found any pic <div ng-repeat="item in vm.data.list">
                  <td> <img ng-src="openweathermap.org/img/w/{{item.weather[0].icon}}"></td>
                </div>

Comment: But in my case it is called a file server. The reason may be that.

Comment: I provided you the _exact_ code to _copy/paste_ now. You forgot the `http://` in the beginning of the url and the `.png` at the end. I tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/0g8ttu97/1/